# Registration Form Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, user-registration

Is There any way to create a shortcode for registration form using

```
<?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_action('register_form');` [doesn't echo the form](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-login.php#L571). It runs inside the form. You can use it to add information or maybe alter some values... maybe. So the answer is that you can't insert the registration form with that mechanism. And while there are function in `wp-login.php`, the form isn't one of them.

What you probably want is [`wp_loginout`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout).

```
function loginout_sc_wpse_107419() {
  wp_loginout();
}
add_shortcode('loginout','loginout_sc_wpse_107419');
```

The form itself is not part of any function that you can reuse, so far as I know. The code for it [is here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-login.php#L533), though. You will have to create that form yourself, using that code as a model.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this displays login or logout link not the registration form.

Comment: @VipinKrSingh : As I said, the form is not part of a function that you can reuse, so far as I know. As "a freelance web designer and developer with 5 years experience in web design and development", per your profile, I think you should be able to manage to create your own form.

Comment: thanks for your advice. First of all, as far as my 5 years experience in web development is concerned, that doesn't say wordpress development. I am new to WordPress, using it from last few months and don't have enough knowledge of WP Development and its terminology. From my previous comment I just wanted to say that I wanted to make a shortcode for registration form. I had no intention to hurt your feelings, if I did so then sorry dear. I am just looking for help not for any sort of verbal war.

Comment: Hurt my feeling? No, not at all. I'm not sure where you got that. I just don't see the need to mock up a form given that I'd basically copy from the Core source code, which link I provided.